# Метод взвешивания терминов

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras, классификация-текста

Нужна помощь с TFC методом взвешивания терминов. Я написал свою функцию, и она работает, но только для небольших объемов данных. При попытке скормить ей тренировочную выборку, она просто зависает.
Вот нейронная сеть:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from string import punctuation
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import itertools
from itertools import zip_longest
import operator
import numpy as np

import keras
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Activation,Dropout,Conv1D,Flatten,MaxPooling1D,GlobalMaxPooling1D
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras import optimizers
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
#nltk.download("stopwords")


pos_train_data = pd.read_csv('train_pos.tsv',sep = '\t')
neg_train_data = pd.read_csv('train_neg.tsv',sep = '\t')
pos_test_data = pd.read_csv('test_pos.tsv',sep = '\t')
neg_test_data = pd.read_csv('test_neg.tsv',sep = '\t')

pos_train_data = pos_train_data[['Text','Sentiment']]
neg_train_data = neg_train_data[['Text','Sentiment']]
pos_test_data = pos_test_data[['Text','Sentiment']]
neg_test_data = neg_test_data[['Text','Sentiment']]


data_train = pd.concat([pos_train_data,neg_train_data],ignore_index = True)
data_train = data_train.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
#print(data_train.head())

data_test = pd.concat([pos_test_data,neg_test_data],ignore_index = True)
data_test = data_test.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
#print(data_test.head())

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
table = str.maketrans('', '', punctuation)

def textclean(text):
    #tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    tokens = (text.lower()).split()
    tokens = [word for word in tokens if word.isalpha()]
    tokens = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
    tokens = [word for word in tokens if not word in stop_words]
    tokens = [word for word in tokens if len(word) > 1]
    return tokens


def review_to_words(text):
    clean_text = BeautifulSoup(text, "html5lib").get_text()
    clean_text = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z]", " ", clean_text)
    words = (clean_text.lower()).split()
    words = [w for w in words if w not in stopwords.words("english")]
    return words


reviews = []
for index,row in data_train.iterrows():
    text = (row['Text'].lower())
    reviews.append(textclean(text))


linked_reviews = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(reviews))
#print(len(linked_reviews))
vocab_freq = dict()
#print(linked_reviews[1])

for word in linked_reviews:
    if word not in vocab_freq:
        vocab_freq[word] = 1
    else:
        vocab_freq[word] += 1
sorted_vocab_freq = list(reversed(sorted(vocab_freq.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))))
#print(sorted_vocab_freq)
#print(len(sorted_vocab_freq))


TOTAL_VOCAB = 5000

word_to_id = dict()
id_to_word = dict()
for i in range(TOTAL_VOCAB):
    word_to_id[sorted_vocab_freq[i][0]] = i
    id_to_word[i] = sorted_vocab_freq[i][0]
print(id_to_word[1])

#review_lengths
review_lengths = pd.DataFrame([len(review) for review in reviews])
review_lengths.columns = ['Len']
#print(review_lengths)
#stats
#print(review_lengths.describe())


def convert(l):
    new_l = []
    for word in l:
        if word in word_to_id:
            new_l.append(word_to_id[word])
    return new_l
#print(len(data_train['Sentiment']))


X_train = []
y_train = []

#Tukey's method
first_q = review_lengths.Len.quantile([0.25])[0.25]
third_q = review_lengths.Len.quantile([0.75])[0.75]

upper_threshold = third_q + 1.5*(third_q-first_q)
lower_threshold = first_q - 1.5*(third_q-first_q)

#print(upper_threshold,lower_threshold)



for i in range(len(data_train)):
    converted_review = convert(reviews[i])
    if len(converted_review) <= 250:
        X_train.append(converted_review)
        y_train.append(data_train['Sentiment'][i])


X_train = np.array(X_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
#print(X_train)
#print(y_train)

X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=int(upper_threshold),value = 0)
#print(X_train.shape,y_train.shape)




data_test = pd.concat([pos_test_data,pos_test_data, neg_test_data], ignore_index=True)
data_test = data_test.sample(frac=0.3).reset_index(drop=True)
#print(data_test)
#print(pos_test_data)
validation_reviews = []
for index, row in data_test.iterrows():
    text = (row['Text'].lower())
    validation_reviews.append(textclean(text))

X_val = []
y_val = []
for i in range(len(data_test)):
    converted_review = convert(validation_reviews[i])
    if len(converted_review) <= upper_threshold:
        X_val.append(converted_review)
        y_val.append(data_test['Sentiment'][i])
X_val = np.array(X_val)
X_val = sequence.pad_sequences(X_val, maxlen=int(upper_threshold), value=0)
#print(X_val)
y_val = np.array(y_val)
#print(X_train)
#print(X_train.shape)
#print(y_train)


EMBEDDING_LEN = 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(TOTAL_VOCAB,EMBEDDING_LEN,input_length = 205))
model.add(Conv1D(256,3,padding = 'same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3,padding = 'same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv1D(32,2,padding = 'same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=4))
model.add(Conv1D(16,2,padding = 'same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(100,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.2, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',optimizer = opt ,metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data = (X_val,y_val),epochs = 1 ,batch_size = 32)
```

А это функция

```
def tfc(slova):
    import math as m
    meshokslov1=[{}for i in range(len(slova))]
    meshokslov2=[{}for i in range(len(slova))]
    SummaKvadratov=0
    for i in range(len(slova)):
        for j in range(len(slova[i])):
            n=0
            for q in slova:
                if q.count(slova[i][j])!=0:
                    n+=1
                    if slova[i][j] in meshokslov1:
                        continue
                    else:
                        meshokslov1[i][slova[i][j]]=slova[i].count(slova[i][j])*m.log10(len(slova)/n)
                        SummaKvadratov+=(slova[i].count(slova[i][j])*m.log10(len(slova)/n))**2
    for i in range(len(slova)):
        for j in range(len(slova[i])):
            if slova[i][j] in meshokslov2:
                continue
            else:
                meshokslov2[i][slova[i][j]]=meshokslov1[i][slova[i][j]]/(SummaKvadratov**0.5)
    return meshokslov2
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75593/discussion-on-question-by-midnight---).

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы посчитать TF-IDF можно воспользоваться готовым решением - [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html).

Пример:

```
In [145]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

In [146]: filename = r'D:\download\aclImdb\train\train_df.csv'

In [147]: df = pd.read_csv(filename)

In [148]: df.shape
Out[148]: (25000, 2)

In [149]: df.head()
Out[149]:
                                              review  sentiment
0  Bromwell High is a cartoon comedy. It ran at t...          1
1  Homelessness (or Houselessness as George Carli...          1
2  Brilliant over-acting by Lesley Ann Warren. Be...          1
3  This is easily the most underrated film inn th...          1
4  This is not the typical Mel Brooks film. It wa...          1

In [150]: vect = TfidfVectorizer()

In [151]: X = vect.fit_transform(df['review'])
```

В результате мы получили разреженную (sparse) матрицу размерности `25000x74849` (2500 документов, 74849 признаков/слов):

```
In [152]: X
Out[152]:
<25000x74849 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 3445861 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если TFC считается по [следующей формуле (5-я страница)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/59b1/ceda2cec08bfbc15a5fbf85fd4511356d97f.pdf):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

то ее можно попробовать имплементировать следующим векторизированным способом:

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse

def tfc(freqs_arr):
    if sparse.isspmatrix_csr(freqs_arr):
        v = freqs_arr
    else:
        v = sparse.csr_matrix(freqs_arr)
    l = sparse.csc_matrix(np.log10(v.shape[0]/(v > 0).sum(axis=0)).reshape(-1))
    v = v.multiply(l)
    denom = v.multiply(v).sum() ** 0.5
    return v / denom
```

где `freqs_arr` - матрица частотных вхождений нормализированных слов.

Пример:

```
In [128]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
```

по умолчанию токены (слова) состоящие из одной буквы игнорируются, поэтому укажем `token_pattern` явно:

```
In [129]: cv = CountVectorizer(token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w+\\b')
```

исходные документы:

```
In [130]: data = ['Help, help, I need help!',  'I will help',  'Will you?']
```

считаем частотную матрицу (`CountVectorizer` нормализует текст по умолчанию):

```
In [131]: X = cv.fit_transform(data)
```

чтобы увидеть результат векторизации (частота вхождения слов) в виде SparseDataFrame:

```
In [132]: d = pd.SparseDataFrame(X, columns=cv.get_feature_names(), default_fill_value=0)

In [133]: d
Out[133]:
   help  i  need  will  you
0     3  1     1     0    0
1     1  1     0     1    0
2     0  0     0     1    1
```

TFC:

```
In [302]: tfc(X)
Out[302]:
<3x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

в виде обычной (dense) матрицы (чтобы вывести на экран в виде матрицы):

```
In [303]: tfc(X).A
Out[303]:
array([[0.56015692, 0.18671897, 0.50591716, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.18671897, 0.18671897, 0.        , 0.18671897, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.18671897, 0.50591716]])
```

Визуализация в виде SparseDataFrame:

```
In [306]: pd.SparseDataFrame(tfc(X), columns=cv.get_feature_names(), default_fill_value=0)
Out[306]:
       help         i      need      will       you
0  0.560157  0.186719  0.505917  0.000000  0.000000
1  0.186719  0.186719  0.000000  0.186719  0.000000
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.186719  0.505917
```

PS за правильность реализации формулы не ручаюсь - надо проверять...

Comment: только как теперь прогнать тренировочную выборку через нее, которая лежит в reviews

Comment: Касаемо моей функции, вот что выдает если подать ваши данные doc=[['Help', 'help', 'I', 'need', 'help'],[ 'I','will','help'],['Will', 'you']]    И вот вывод:             [{'Help': 0.23905705128951346, 'help': 0.17645768965980294, 'I': 0.08822884482990147, 'need': 0.23905705128951346}, {'I': 0.08822884482990147, 'will': 0.23905705128951346, 'help': 0.08822884482990147}, {'Will': 0.23905705128951346, 'you': 0.23905705128951346}]

Comment: А то что вы говорили по ТF-IDF, как его можно реализовать?

Comment: а как можно реализовать ваш метод с вычислением tfc, но только чтобы разделителем являлась не запятая, а подсписок, т.е данные выглядят не так data = ['Help, help, I need help!',  'I will help',  'Will you?'] А так data = [['Help', 'help', 'I', 'need', 'help'], ['I', 'will', 'help'],  ['Will' ,'you'']]

Comment: @Midnight, самый простой вариант - преобразовать к такому виду как в ответе: `data = [' '.join(x) for x in data]`