# Векторизация списка

Tags: python, список, текст

Нужна помощь с векторизацией списка. Список состоит из вложенных списков(каждый вложенный список это отдельный документ), а те  в свою очередь из набора терминов, например `list = [['film','help']['will','you']]`. Нужно каждый термин в этом списке заменить числом, которое считается по формуле https://i.stack.imgur.com/73xj9.png. Написал свою функцию, но она работает неверно.

```
def tfc(slova):
    import math as m
    meshokslov1=[{}for i in range(len(slova))]
    meshokslov2=[{}for i in range(len(slova))]
    SummaKvadratov=0
    for i in range(len(slova)):
        for j in range(len(slova[i])):
            n=0
            for q in slova:
                if q.count(slova[i][j])!=0:
                    n+=1
                    if slova[i][j] in meshokslov1:
                        continue
                    else:
                        meshokslov1[i][slova[i][j]]=slova[i].count(slova[i][j])*m.log10(len(slova)/n)
                        SummaKvadratov+=(slova[i].count(slova[i][j])*m.log10(len(slova)/n))**2
    for i in range(len(slova)):
        for j in range(len(slova[i])):
            if slova[i][j] in meshokslov2:
                continue
            else:
                meshokslov2[i][slova[i][j]]=meshokslov1[i][slova[i][j]]/(SummaKvadratov**0.5)
    return meshokslov2
```

Comment: "она работает неверно." не могли бы вы уточнить, что имено не верно?

Comment: @Unick, неверно считает

Comment: могу посоветовать рассчитать всё на листочки, а потом сравнить с выполнением программы. На каком этапе происходит ошибка.

Comment: Ваш алгоритм имеет сложность `O(N^3)`. Даже для небольшого корпуса  это функция будет работать неприлично долго. Для среднего или больше корпуса у вас кроме проблем со скоростью обработки, скорее всего, не хватит памяти. Расчет необходимого (для вашего алгоритма) объема памяти для корпуса, состоящего из 50.000 документов и 100.000 уникальных слов: `2*50000*100000*8/1024**3` = `74.5GiB`

Comment: Возможный дупликат вопроса: ["Метод взвешивания терминов"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/809558/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2)